# Post escaped Javascript array and unescape it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, escaping

I have some javascript code that gets the value of two html form input fields. I escaped the values to allow users to enter in special characters and then placed them into an array that is stringified and then posted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var BuilderName = escape($('[name=BuilderName]').val());
    var OwnersName = escape($('[name=OwnersName]').val());
    var arraydata = [BuilderName, OwnersName];
    $.post("DCF_Update_Query.php", {
      data: JSON.stringify(arraydata)
    }, function() {
         alert('Successful');
       }).fail(function() {
            alert('Failed');
          });
  });
});
```

In my PHP file I retrieve and decode the array and insert it into my database.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO dcf (BuilderName, OwnersName)
VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]')");
```

My problem is that the escaped characters are entering in the database as `%26`, `%27`, etc.. How can I un-escape those characters and then re-escape them using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Also, I've heard that `json_decode()` automatically escapes special characters. If this is the case, then do I even need to escape them with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? I'd greatly appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: If you just bind parameters you don't need to worry about escaping. You should not be doing this `"INSERT INTO dcf (BuilderName, OwnersName)
VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]')"`.

Comment: I think those values are url encoded, so you should just be able to `urldecode($val)` to convert `%26` back. If not url encoded, then it will be `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really, really, REALLY need a prepared statement here. No escaping needed

```
$prep = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dcf (BuilderName, OwnersName) VALUES (?, ?)");
$prep->bind_param('ss', $data[0], $data[1]);
$prep->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work after I removed escape() from the javascript. For some reason I thought the javascript was breaking when I entered a ' into the form input. Also a thanks to Rasclatt who suggested this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the contents of your $data variable through the urldecode function:

```
$data = urldecode(json_decode($_POST['data']));
```